# c# auto generated partial class redefine property get set

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, partial-classes

I'm moving from mainly classic asp to .NET. So this may be a stupid question, but I can't find an answer.

I have an MVC App using Database First and Entity Framework. Now I would like to add some logic to the auto generated 'partial' classes. From what I have read it should be a matter of creating a new partial class with the same namespace and name. But when I do that I get an error "(This member is defined more than once)" and  "Ambiguity between [partial class] and [partial class]". I understand what the error is saying, but I'm not sure how to resolve the problem.

I would like to add some logic to the set; accessor.

So in the generated class I have

```
public partial class QualityChecks
{
.....
    public int DailyCount { get; set; }
...
}
```

in my new partial class I would like to add to the set code to make sure only values greater then 0 are added. If a negative value is added it needs to be logged and changed to 0
e.g. my new partial class is:

```
public partial class QualityChecks    {
public int DailyCount         {        
set
        {
            DailyCount = value;
            if it's < 0 log and set to 0
        }

    }
```

If that's not clear maybe this will help:
Currently I have loads of code that simply does

```
QualityChecks qc = new QualityChecks();
qc.DailyCount = enteredAmount;
....
db.QualityChecks.add(qc);
```

Rather then update that logic everywhere it would be nice to have it wrapped up in the QualityChecks class.

Is this the right way of going about it? If so what do I need to change to make this work?

Thank you in advance for any tips and help!

Comment: As an alternative, have you considered this idea: keep these entity classes just within you repository code. Then use something like https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper to map between these entity classes and other data classes that can contain the checks you require. That way. you avoid issues with partial classes.

Comment: funnily enough I am using Automapper elsewhere in this project, works great. I hadn't though of using like that. It's probably my inexperience talking but creating a new class & mapping feels messier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot define the same members in two different files.

You can try to define a new wrapper property (eg. MyDailyCount) that add that extra logic and update the underlying DailyCount at the end so it get persisted to database.

```
public int MyDailyCount 
{
   get { return DailyCount; }
   set 
   { 
         DailyCount = value; 
         // your extra logic 
    }
}
```

Comment: So everywhere in the resest of my code where i have qc.DailyCount = enteredAmount; would need to be changed to qc.MyDailyCount = enteredAmount; ?

Comment: Yes. Other options is change the name of the property mapped to the database to (eg DbDailyCount) and use DailyCount as the name for the wrapper property. You can think as well decoupling the classes you use for the Database entities with the entities in your model (the ones that have the logic) and transform from one to the other.

Comment: The only extra change I would like to have is to make the autoGenerated property private. Is there a way of setting that permanently or will I have to make that change every time I update the model?

Comment: Not sure. Ideally you don't want to do that kind of things on autogenerated properties, you want them at least protected virtual so EF can do his magic on them (lazy loading, etc)