# Transforming data from LINQ-to-SQL as soon as they are read from SQL

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I use LINQ-to-SQL to extract and save data from/to SQL Server.

Suppose I have the proverbial `Products` table, which has a field named `Description`. The field is free-text and as such it may contain newlines. To avoid Windows/Unix newline issues, I may decide to replace "\r\n" to "\n". However, I want to perform this substitution as early as possible, ideally right as the data is received from SQL Server. This way, `myDataContext.Products` would return `Product` objects whose description only contains "\n".

How can I do that?

**EDIT**

I know I can do this by calling `Select()`. However, I'd have to call the `Select()` every time I use the `Products` table.

Let me explain by showing some code. I have a `DataManager` class that wraps the reading/writing logic. It has a few methods like these:

```
public Product GetProduct(int i_id)
{
    return m_database.Products.Where(p => p.Id == i_id).FirstOrDefault();
}

public Product GetProductByName(string i_name)
{
    return m_database.Products.Where(p => p.Name == i_name).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Here, `m_database` is the data context, and `Products` is a `System.Data.Linq.Table`. Surely, I could call `Select()` on each of these lines, but it would be against DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself), and would actually be WET (Write Everything Twice). That's why I'm looking for a way to include the transformation "inside" `Products`, so that just calling `m_database.Products` returns the transformed data.

Comment: What do you mean? Transforming is what the `select` clause in your LINQ-to-SQL query does. What did you try? What does the code look like? Why do this in the query instead of the *property setter*? SQL, the language, is awful when it comes to string manipulation

Comment: I know I could do this with `Select()`, but I would need to do it every time I consume the `Products` LINQ `Table`. I'd rather avoid having to do it every time - I'd prefer having the `Products` table already transformed.

Comment: If you want to have `the Products table already transformed` clean the data when it's *written*. Otherwise you'll *have* to transform the data each time you read it no matter the API or driver you use.

Comment: This doesn't guarantee what I get when I read. If someone manually edited the DB (which I can't prevent from happening), I'd get the wrong data anyway.

Comment: Then transform. Or use an INSTEAD-OF trigger that alwasy cleans the data. The question doesn't make any sense, unless you assume there's some connection or driver switch that detects and modifies newlines. There isn't. SQL, the language, doesn't care about newlines. They are just characters stored in fields

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos We are saying the same thing. I don't expect Linq-to-SQL to perform the transformation in my stead. I know I have to write the code myself. BUT, I want to put that code as close as possible to the "SQL side" of the process. Is this clearer?

Comment: No, you are saying something completely different. You assume there's a magic transformation you can perform that won't require you to write `REPLACE(somefield,CHAR(10),'')`. There isn't. The Linq-to-SQL equivalent *is* `String.Replace`. That may be translated to `REPLACE(somefield,CHAR(10),'')`, maybe not and you'll have to use a utility function. In this case it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Ok. I don't want to have to call `m_database.Products.Select(p => new Product { /* all the other fields = p.fields */, Description = p.Description.Replace("\r\n", "\n") })` every time I need to get `Products`. I want that projection wrapped SOMEHOW inside `Products`. A metadata class? Inheriting the `Product` class? An extension method? I don't know how to do it (I'm asking).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
products.Select(p => new Product 
                     { 
                         Id = p.Id,
                         Description = p.Description.Replace("\r\n", "\n")
                     });
```

Or possibly a custom getter...

```
public class Product
{
    private string _description;

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description
    {
        get
        {
            return _description.Replace("\r\n", "\n");
        }
        set
        {
            _description = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I need to clarify this point. This works, but I have to do it every time. Let me edit the question.

Comment: @Simone perhaps you need to rethink the question. If the stored data doesn't match what you want you'll *have* to transform it every time you read it

Comment: Are you using an ORM, if so, which one?

Comment: No ORM, except for Linq-To-Sql (which, AFAIK, is not actually an ORM).

Comment: Yes @PanagiotisKanavos, exactly, but I want to call that transformation as low as possible down the call tree. I don't want the client code to transform it.

Comment: @SteveJ, this is close to what I want, but in your example `_description` would be what Linq-to-sql gets from the DB. However, Linq-to-SQL actually sets the property.

Comment: @Simone there's no transformation lower than `SELECT`. The database doesn't care about newlines. If you wrote a `SELECT` statement directly, wouldn't you *have* to remove unwanted characters?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos We're getting confused. I'm talking about the `Select()` projection method of LINQ, you're talking about the SQL `SELECT` statement. Also, newlines are just an example: I may want to capitalize, or remove spaces, or whatever.

Comment: @Simone you'll keep getting confused because `Select()` is the thing that gets translated to `SELECT`. If you want something to appear in `SELECT` it **has** to be written in `Select()`. Linq to SQL is ancient and may or may not be smart enough to convert `String.Replace` to `REPLACE`

Comment: @Simone, Linq-to-SQL would set the property, but the overridden get method would format it how you require when you read it...

Comment: @SteveJ You're right - I had misread your code. Would this also mean that, on saving to the DB, the corrected data would be written? I'll test it right away.

Comment: @SteveJ I ended up using your solution, but I kept the property that was being used before. I renamed it, as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30805127/c-sharp-auto-generated-partial-class-redefine-property-get-set

Answer (score 1):

I would probably extend some of the core Linq features you use.

Ex:

```
public static class ProductQueryExtensions
{
    public static List<Product> CleanSelect(this IQueryable<Product> q)
    {
        return q.Select(p => new Product 
        { 
            Id = p.Id,
            Description = p.Description.Replace("\r\n", "\n")
        }).ToList();
    }

    public static Product CleanFirstOrDefault(this IQueryable<Product> q)
    {
        return q.CleanSelect().FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Then your example code would become:

```
return m_database.Products.Where(p => p.Id == i_id).CleanFirstOrDefault();
```